# The electron's charge/mass ratio

Tags: electrons, charge

In my physics laboratory class, we were discussing the following results after conducting experiments to determine the charge-mass ratio, $e/m$, of the electron. In the experiment, electrons were accelerated and executed circular motion perpendicular to a homogeneous magnetic field which was produced by a pair of Helmholtz coils. The voltage, radius, and strength of the magnetic field could be used to determine the ratio $e/m$.

Many of us obtained a positive result as outcome for this ratio, whilst a few other people returned almost the exact same value, however negative. Their reasoning was that the ratio being negative makes sense since we're dividing the negative charge by a positive mass; hence a negative result.

This sounded right at first, however, isn't it about the magnitude of the charge, which you have to divide by the mass (hence dividing a positive value by positive mass, resulting in a positive oucome)?

I'm trying to understand what's the correct way to view these outcomes. Should this ratio be positive or negative, and why? Is one of us correct in their reasoning?

Replies are much appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-to-charge_ratio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most definitely the magnitude of charge that matters, reversing the charge all it does is make a mirror image circle, so since in your experiment, you are measuring inherently sign-less/directionless parameters like radius, time, and magnetic field, speed etc. You would get a positive value for e/m. **However**, when you do report the value of $e/m$, you must report it with a sign, i.e negative. So, the ratio should be negative but, from the experiment As we are dealing with directionless quantities, you get a positive number as an output for the experiment, but when someone asks for the specific charge, not the magnitude then you report it with a sign.

Comment: The experiment does not deal with directionless quantities, the magnetic field orientation is known. The experiment can be used to determine the charge of the particles in the beam, and thus the proper sign of the reported value of e/m.

Answer (score 2):

The charge to mass ratio should be negative for exactly the reasons stated (charge is negative, mass is positive), and you can determine this from the information obtained during the experiment. You know the direction of the initial velocity of the electron beam from looking at the source (and the beam diverging as it travels away from it), and you should know the direction of current in the Helmholtz coils from which you can work out the direction of the magnetic field which is applied to the electrons. From these, you can use the right hand rule with the Lorentz force law
$$
\vec{F} = q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})
$$
(with $\vec{E}=0$) to determine which direction the particle beam should loop if the particles are negatively charged. If you worked out each of these parameters properly, you should find that the force causes them to loop in the direction you observe if they are negatively charged, and that they would loop in the opposite direction if positively charged.